# Z-index of KML layers

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I use Google Map v3. I have a map and there are KML layers inside. My problem is that the big KML area is put on top of the small KML area so it's impossible to click on the small one to view its information. 
Is it possible to determine whether an KML layer is smaller or bigger than other KML simply from its url?
How do I resolve this situation?

Comment: KML is a markup language– it's not used for rendering directly. There are multiple KML-renderer, most using SVG to render the elements.

Comment: I can't change from kml to svg because my client use kml

Comment: You could try to change the order of the elements within the KML.

Comment: All I have are KML urls get from a server. Then I use these url to create and render KML object using javascript. It's impossible to change the order of KML file order without knowing the size of the KML areas

Comment: How complex is your KML?  Can you use a third party KML parser to display it (that would render the polygons as native Google Maps API v3 objects and you could then reorder them)?

Comment: Manually reordering is not the solution, the list of KML file are added and remove dynamically by the user. The KML zones differ as the search filter differ. So my real question is: from simply 2 urls of KML file, how do you detect whether one KML area is bigger/smaller than the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Another remember helped me with this issue I was having.

```
var layer1= new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'layer1.kml',
});
var layer2= new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'layer2.kml',
    pane: "floatPane",
    preserveViewport: true
});
```

You can try adding

```
 pane: "floatPane",
        preserveViewport: true
```